# Redirecting to another page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a quiz in javascript and I am using HTML forms to present it. I have verifed all of the users answers with if statements and if they get it either right or wrong a prompt box pops up to ask if they want to try again. When they say yes the quiz starts again but when they say no nothing happens and I would like it to automatically redirect itself to my homepage. Does anyone know how to do that? My website is not on a server it needs to be able to run off a CD or a USB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://yourhomepage.com";`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location). here's an example:

`window.location.replace("yourpage.htm");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the window.location object:

```
window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location` There are many ways. my favourite is

```
window.location.href = "http://yourhomepage.com";
```